# Change value of parent inside component called in ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Using angular 7, I am trying to pass an object to a child component inside a ngFor loop, but when i change the value inside, it doesn't change on the parent.

In my parent i have

```
<div class="pieceContainer" *ngFor="let piece of data?.piece">
  <app-piece [(data)]="piece" (change)="doSomething(event$)"></app-piece>
</div>
```

In my child i have the following, i change the value of data inside a modal and i try to output it:

```
@Input() data: any;
@Output() change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

When from the modal i change the data and i press save, i call:

```
this.change.emit(this.data);
```

Does anybody have a clue of why it doesn't update the objects values in the parent component?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
@Output() dataChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the shared data. Just minor change in:

```
<app-piece [data]="piece" (change)="doSomething('data')"></app-piece>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for some people interested, the answer was simply putting $event instead of event$.